# How can I press key of "keycode 53" every minute in X?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, window-manager, openbsd

I want to automate my typing. I can use window managers such as gnome and fvwm.

I can access to ubuntu and obsd.

Comment: Your Question is not much clear. Please explain it in clear format.

Comment: @SHW: I am not sure what it is, sometimes it is called userspace macro but I want just that keys are pressed according to some pattern in X. By X, I mean that I want it work with programs in X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tools to simulate a key press, for example [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/). Although the [underlying interface](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XSendEvent.3.xhtml) uses keycodes, `xdotool` does the job of translating keysyms back into keysyms, which is usually very convenient.

If you really need to specify a keycode, I don't know of a command line utility for that, but you can write a small C or python or $favorite_language program¹. Again, you almost always want to specify keysyms, not keycodes.

To do something every minute, either put it in a crontab, or write a shell loop (you probably want the latter, so you can kill it easily):

```
while sleep 60; do xdotool key A; done
```

¹  <sub>I might be able to dig up some Python if there's demand.</sub>

Comment: ...for python there is always D!